# How to insert content inside a new page while using a template?

Tags: php, html

**Hi, I'm a student and I had this little problem while doing a job.**

What I'm trying to do is create a new page using a button, but the problem that i'm having is that the page isn't printing anything that I code, so it stays with only the template inserted

The code that i'm using for the button:

```
<a href="dataHandling.php">
<p style="background-color:#67524c;color:#ffffff;font-size: 13px;padding: 10px 15px 10px; text-upper; max-width:max-content; margin:auto;">Data Handling</p>
</a>
```

even if the dataHandling.php is empty the template remains, and I can't add anything to it!

Comment: You have to <a href="data.php"> to redirect to this page and write what you want in it

Comment: @Mathieu27 So I tried to use the extension on the file, but still none echo or prints on the page.

Even if I add this code to dataHandling.php
```
<?php 
echo "<h1> Hello World!</h1>";
?>

```
the page returns like this:
https://www.gelcopep.com/en/dataHandling.php

Comment: https://www.gelcopep.com/en/dataHandling.php contains quite a lot of stuff. But data.php != dataHandling.php. It's unclear what the issue is. Have you looked at the View Source screen in your browser to see what's actually in the data.php page when it's blank?

Comment: @ADyson On the View Source, the only thing that shows is the template of the website and js connections. The issue is that I'm trying to add content to this page, but when I code it, it doesn't change anything but stills the same.

Comment: Well we don't know anything about your site or how it's built, all you showed us is one hyperlink (which seems to just link the dataHandling.php page back to itself!). Maybe you're overwriting the wrong copy of the page, or maybe it's some sort of CMS where you're supposed add content another way, or maybe the template stuff gets added by a separate process, or maybe something else...we have no idea just from what you told us. Even visiting the site doesn't inform us about how the back-end works or what your deployment environment is like.

Comment: I noticed something, even if I change the href to anything a new page will open with the template, even if theres no .php/.html of it on the server, so this might be the issue...

Comment: It's probably a CMS, or maybe an MVC framework with a routing engine which redirects requests through a central system to work out what content to display, instead of relying on individual physical files. You need to find out how the application actually works - it clearly isn't just a "basic" PHP application.

Comment: @ADyson it was not a CMS, but a Framework, I solved it by using the direct URL of the content that I need to insert! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. But please do not add "SOLVED" to your question title. That's not how this site works, we're not a forum. Add the answer below, where it says "Your Answer" instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . Thanks :-)

Comment: Please also take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (which you were recommended to do when you created your account, but I can see by the lack of relevant badge in your profile, that you haven't) so you have a better idea how things work around here.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll do that, thanks again for the help. :D

Answer (score 1):

**I solved the issue and here how I've done it:**

Instead of trying to open the .pdf content inside a .php, I uploaded the entire .pdf on the server, and copied the **URL that FireZilla provided**, then I pasted the URL inside the `<a href="URL">` of the button on the HTML!

After that I just tested the button and it did what I needed for this case, it was opening the .pdf after pressing the button!

Comment: Ah ok. It would have made sense to mention originally that you were trying to embed a pdf, that's a specific task. Glad you found something that works for you.